# Cannot find all files in requirements.txt

Tags: git, pip

I've a requirements.txt file I'm trying to install using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  There are 4 rows it does not install, namely:

```
-e git+http://repo/repo/django-newsletter.git@443f23025471eb605b23d3bd36dc12447bb463a0#egg=newsletter-dev
-e git+http://repo/repo/django-richtext.git@d2ce2184b743efe1ef3195e3ae298944a107bcaa#egg=richtext-master
-e git+http://repo/repo/django-subscribers.git@e45da03e73ae7fce34bf89025b214e11252ef553#egg=subscribers-master
-e git+http://repo.queo.pt/repo/django-bounce_checker.git@ca10c94aa3b9c38348ce330ab9e7116929fa56df#egg=bounce_checker-dev
```

I've never really bothered to look at a `requirements.txt` file before but these appear to be git calls rather than a typical install.  Is there something else I should be doing?

Also, I can find two of these (I believe) on git, namely `django-newsletter` and `django-subscribers` but not the other two.  Any ideas what they might be?

Comment: `//repo/` suggests it was some internal Git repository of whoever wrote the requirements.txt. Ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was as RemcoGerlich suggested - the code was it private Git repositories

Answer (score 0):

> I've never really bothered to look at a requirements.txt file before but these appear to be git calls rather than a typical install. Is there something else I should be doing?

Yes: read the documentation for Pip, and [what those requirements specifications mean](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

Pip can install distributions [specified as Git specifiers](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git):

> pip supports installing from Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar, and detects the type of VCS using url prefixes: "git+", "hg+", "bzr+", "svn+".